# Dynamics AX installation WS

Tags: axapta

I would like to install dynamics AX but I get always this same problem "The CRC in GZip footer does not match the CRC calculated from the decompressed data" Do you know what should I do?
Here I added log from my computer:

```
 === Setup logging started: 2012-05-18 07:45:10 === 
Running file: "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AxSetup\AxSetup.exe" RelatedFilesDir="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder (2)" 
AxSetup version number: 5.0.593.0
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0 (64 bit)
ABD
CORP\Administrator
Interactive: True

RelatedFilesDir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder (2)
Property RelatedFilesDir set to: 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder (2)\'
Property SetupLanguage set to: 'EN'

=== Loading parameters from the command line or a parameter file === 
Initializing log file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Dynamics AX\Dynamics AX Setup Logs\2012-05-18 07-45-10\DynamicsSetupLog.txt

 === Starting evaluation of existing installation state === 
MSI file: Components64.msi  Installed: False
MSI file: ClientHelp.msi  Installed: False


 === Checking parameters === 
Property InstallPath set to: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50'
Property InstallPath32Bit set to: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50'

 === Starting UI phase === 
Property AcceptLicenseTerms set to: '1'
Property BypassWarnings set to: '0'
Property RunMode set to: 'DeveloperComponents'
Property InstallAnalysisServicesExtensions set to: '0'
Property InstallAos set to: '1'
Property ClientAosServer set to: 'ABD'
Property InstallApplication set to: '1'
Property InstallAifWebServices set to: '0'
Property InstallBizTalkAdapter set to: '0'
Property InstallClientUI set to: '1'
Property InstallComBusinessConnector set to: '0'
Property InstallDatabase set to: '1'
Property InstallEnterprisePortal set to: '0'
Property InstallNetBusinessConnector set to: '1'
Property InstallDebugger set to: '1'
Property InstallEnterprisePortalTools set to: '0'
Property InstallReportingServicesExtensions set to: '0'
Property InstallReportingTools set to: '0'
Property InstallSynchronizationProxy set to: '0'
Property InstallSynchronizationService set to: '0'
Property InstallWorkflow set to: '0'
Property DbServerType set to: '0'
Property InstallDatabase set to: '1'
Performing  prerequisite validation: DhtmlEd
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ 64 bit SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: SNAC
Property DbServerType set to: '0'
Property InstallDatabase set to: '0'
Performing  prerequisite validation: DhtmlEd
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: VC++ 64 bit SP1
Performing  prerequisite validation: SNAC
Property InstallPath set to: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50'
Property InstallPath32Bit set to: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50'
Property DbSqlServer set to: 'ABD'
Connected to SQL Server: 'ABD'
Connected to SQL Server: 'ABD'
Property DbSqlDatabaseName set to: 'Dynamicsx1'
Property InstallApplication set to: '2'
Property ApplicationInstanceName set to: 'Dynamicsx1'
Property ApplicationRegion set to: '-'
Property AosPort set to: '2712'
Property AosInstanceName set to: 'Dynamicsx1'
Property AosPort set to: '2712'
Property AosReportErrors set to: '0'
    The localized name for the NT Authority\Network Service account has been identified as 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
Property AosAccount set to: ''
Property ClientLanguage set to: 'EN-US'
Property ClientHelpLanguages set to: 'EN-US'
Property AosStart set to: '1'

 === Starting execution phase === 
=== Setting up Application files === 
An error occurred during setup of Application files.
Setup could not copy folder C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder (2)\Application to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50\Application.
Reason: The CRC in GZip footer does not match the CRC calculated from the decompressed data.


 === Setup was canceled or failed. For details see the previous messages in the log.

 === Setup logging ended: 2012-05-18 07:49:09 ErrorLevel/ExitCode: '1' ===
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation files may be corrupt.

If you downloaded the files, then retry you download.

Comment: The same after download? The source may be corrupt! Have you tried installing on another machine?

Comment: I will check this when I will back home. If I will have problems I will send you message.

Comment: Can you look on my new problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718229/dynamics-ax-2009-user-group-permission