# Dynamics AX 2009 "user group permission"

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to prepare very fast "user group permission" but this is very difficult for example  If I would like to add access for Administration ->Location View this software give only permission for parent but not for all nodes in this parent. What should I do to fix this problem?

[image]

If I will click Dimension sets I need make permission to all child in this parent. Do you know what I have to do?

```
public void MCOVgrantFullAccess(SecurityKeySet _startSecurityKeySet = null)
{
    //klasa systemowa dictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa600103(v=ax.50).aspx
    Dictionary          dictionary = new Dictionary();

    DictSecurityKey     dictSecurityKey;
    int i;


    if (_startSecurityKeySet)
        securitySet = _startSecurityKeySet;
    else
        securitySet = SysSecurity::constructSecurityKeySet();


    // securityKeyCnt() An integer that indicates the number of security keys. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa600103(v=ax.50).aspx
    // i = 365
    for (i=dictionary.securityKeyCnt(); i; i--)
    {
        dictSecurityKey = new DictSecurityKey(dictionary.securityKeyCnt2Id(1));
        if (!dictSecurityKey.parentSecurityKeyId())
        {
            securitySet.access(dictSecurityKey.id(), AccessType::Delete);
        }
    }
    SysSecurityFormSetup::delete(userGroupId, domainId); //Delete setup of form controls
    formSetupMap = new Map(Types::String, Types::Class); //Clear cache
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting up security there is a process which 'should' be followed, you start with gathering processes end-users carry out, define the security roles based on these processes and then set up the groups. I have been trained by MS Partners in security and we never hard-coded anything. There is a set area for security in the Administration module, in here you can define user groups and the permissions within, then assign users to a group, can also set up record level security from here for individual records.